# if else condition in routes laravel

Tags: laravel

I want only user with same name with the url id can access using ***if condition***

Example

- User logged on with name jer
- He should only access url with /User-Profile/jer
- And not access other page /User-Profile/abc that are not equal to his
  name

Doing something like Example:

```
 if{id}!=={{auth->name}}
 {
  Route::get('NoPermission', 'Restriction@index');
 }
 else
 {
  Route::get('/User-Profile/{name}/', 'AccountController@index');
 }
```

How can I compare `{name}` from url to `{auth->name}` ?

***Route***

```
 Route::get('/User-Profile/{name}/', 'AccountController@index');
```

***Blade***

```
 <a href="/dashboard/User-Profile/{{ Auth::user()->name }}">{{ Auth::user()->name 
}}</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't access Auth like that in your routes, compare it in your AccountController instead:

```
public function index($name){
    if($name != Auth::user->name()) abort(403);
    else...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a service provider (Doesn't really matter which one, but it would be clearer if done in the RouteServiceProvider), add a route binding in the boot method as documented in https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding

```php
public function boot()
{
    // Declare binding 'name'. 
    Route::bind('name', function ($name) { 
        return App\User::where('name', $name)->first() ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```

Then, use that binding in your routes file

```php
// Use binding name and middleware auth to make sure this route can't be accessed by guest users.
Route::get('/User-Profile/{name}/', 'AccountController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('account_profile');
```

In your blade file, you can do the following

```xml
{{-- Make sure the link is only visible for authenticated users https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#if-statements --}}
@auth
  <a href="{{ route('account_profile', ['name' => auth()->user()->name]) }}</a>
@endauth
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow acces to the page , but before showing content ,check if the url path is == to the id name .

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can check in your routes like this:

```
Route::get('/profile/{name}', function(String $name) {
    if (!Auth::check() || $name !== Auth::user()->name) {
        abort(404);
    }
    return view("view.auth.profile", ['profile => App\Profile::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->first()]);
});
```

However if you use

`Route::get('/profile', 'AuthController@profile')->middleware('auth');`

and use `Auth::user()` in your controller to select the correct profile.

The benefit here is that any unauthenticated users will be automatically redirected to your login page, and there's no need to include the name on your profile link.